# Three.js reverse rotation

Tags: math, 3d, three.js, euler-angles

I'm placing Object3Ds in a scene with coordinates from an older Away3D project. The issue I'm having is when objects have a negative position.x (i.e. behind the camera), the rotation is opposite.

I'm only using X and Z for tilt and spin.

Is there a way to calculate the opposite/flip side angles so it flips?

i.e.  if x =  1.69, what should the direct opposite be?

Here is my current attempt:

```
        photo.rotation.x = data.rotationX != null 
            ? photo.position.x < 0 
                    ? Math.PI - data.rotationX
                    : data.rotationX
            : 0;

        photo.position.x < 0 
            ? photo.rotation.z = Math.PI
            : photo.rotation.z = 0;

        photo.rotation.y = data.rotationY != null 
                ? photo.position.x < 0 
                        ? Math.PI - data.rotationY
                        : data.rotationY
            : 0;
```

EDIT: Doing some further research on this, is it possible the Three.js way of calculating angles is going to be different from the Away3d one? i.e. a similar problem here [3D rotation with Axis & Angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809788/3d-rotation-with-axis-angle)

It's very strange. Some of the objects are good and the same as they are in Away3d, and some are on strange angles that are not anywhere near the same.